# Capybara session not closing at end of test

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver, rspec, capybara

I have a series of automated tests using selenium/capybara/rspec. For one of my tests, I am dirtying a form and verifying that certain errors are triggered. That is the end of the test... The problem is that when the test finishes running, the and the code tries to close the browser, a JavaScript message pops up with `This page is asking you to confirm that you want to leave - data you have entered may not be saved.`

In my spec helper I have:

```
Capybara.register_driver :firefox do |app|
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :firefox)
end

Capybara.default_driver = :firefox
Capybara.app_host = ********* #redacted
Capybara.default_max_wait_time = 5

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:each) do
    config.include Capybara::DSL
  end

  config.after(:each) do
    Capybara.reset_sessions!
  end
end
```

and am getting a test failure with `Capybara::ExpectationNotMet: Timed out waiting for Selenium session reset`

How do I make the test close the browser at the end?

Answer (score 1):

You don't indicate what browser and version of the browser you're using (for instance FF 59 has recently made a change that makes handling unload modals more difficultg to deal with) nor any other versions of the test gems you're using, so it's tough to say whether or not your current issue would be fixed by upgrading (it may).  However you can work around this issue in the tests where you know an unload modal will appear by adding

```
accept_confirm do
  visit("about:blank") # or any page in your app that doesn't have an unload modal ( / for instance )
end
```

to the end of those specific tests.  That could be implemented in after block triggered by metadata on the feature if you want to keep your actual test code clean. To implement it via metadata you'd change your RSpec configure block to something like

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:each) do
    config.include Capybara::DSL
  end

  config.after(:each, clear_unload_modal: true) do
    accept_confirm do # may need to be Capybara.current_session.accept_confirm depending on your includes
      visit("/") # may need to be Capybara.current_session.visit
    end
  end

  config.after(:each) do
    Capybara.reset_sessions!
  end
end
```

and then tag each test that needs it with :clear_unload_modal

```
scenario "blah blah", :clear_unload_modal do
  ....
end
```

Comment: Added some content to the question that might better address the issue.

Comment: @Zack You still haven't stated what version of FF you're using - if 59 then you'll need to use the master branch of Capybara for this to work without you doing anything else.  Did you try calling the code in my answer at the end of your tests that pop up the question?

Comment: I'm on 58.0.2 64-bit. That code does work but it requires me to insert that at the end of every test that ends that way. It feels like a hacky way to handle the problem. I do appreciate the solution though.

Comment: @Zack This shouldn't be an issue with FF 58 if you're using the latest geckodriver and capybara (it's specifically tested for in the Capybara test suite).  As for the work around code, as I stated in my answer you wouldn't actually need to insert it at the end of every test if you put it in an after block triggered by metadata, I've expanded my answer to spell that out step by step.